Data Length Extension on IW612 for Imx93 board
I am trying to update data length extension on BLE on Imx93 board. Using python, i am unable to find any library which support DLE negotiations.
Its IW612 so NXP has a pdf which says, we can do following but I am unable to find how to do it?  I am unable to locate their library to do these changes.
bleResult_tGap_UpdateLeDataLength
(
deviceId_t deviceId,
uint16_t txOctets,
uint16_t txTime
);

This is certainly a question you should ask your board manufacturer, who will probably supply a BSP for it.
